# Java Incorrect syntax near '0'

Tags: java, database

I'm having problems trying to insert the values into my database.

When i do the code below it works

```
insertString = "insert into Players     
values(1,'Fred','Fish','fredfish@gamer.net','Ithroeann',19770322)";
statement.executeUpdate(insertString);
```

but when I try to do this look here it gives me an incorrect syntax near '0' error

I'm trying to loop it to add it automatically through a file

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("players.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) {
        String[] temp;
        String str = input.next();
            temp = str.split("\\|");

insertString = "insert into Players values(temp[0], temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4],temp[5])";
        statement.executeUpdate(insertString);
}
```

Comment: could u pls post the full class?

Comment: Are you getting a compile-time java syntax error or runtime SQL syntax error? SQL is invalid for sure, it won't access java variables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a String. If you want to append elements of the temp array to the String, you can't do it this way.

You can do it like this :

```
insertString = "insert into Players values("+temp[0]+",'"+temp[1]+"','"+temp[2]+"','"+temp[3]+"','"+temp[4]+"',"+temp[5]+")";
statement.executeUpdate(insertString);
```

Of course using a PreparedStatement would be a much better solution.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Players values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
stmt.setInt (1, Integer.parseInt(temp[0]));
stmt.setString (2, temp[1]);
stmt.setString (3, temp[2]); 
stmt.setString (4, temp[3]); 
stmt.setString (5, temp[4]);
stmt.setInt (6, Integer.parseInt(temp[5]));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I was wondering why it wouldn't work as it worked on paper

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PreparedStatement` to bind your query parameters as

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement(
       "insert into Players values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// index starts from 1
int i = 1;
// bind first int value
pStmt.setInt(i, Integer.parseInt(temp[0]));

// bind string values
for (; i < temp.length; i++)
    pStmt.setString(i, temp[i-1]);

// bind last int value
pStmt.setInt(i, Integer.parseInt(temp[i-1]));

// execute insert
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code posted above is partial, it seems like you're missing the statement preparation part. Try something like the following:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("players.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) {
        String[] temp;
        String str = input.next();
            temp = str.split("\\|");

dbConnection = getDBConnection(); // Implement this method based on your DB configuration

String insertString = "insert into Players values(?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
statement.setInt(temp[0]); // int, or whichever type you have
statement.setInt(temp[1]); // int, or whichever type you have
statement.setInt(temp[2]); // int, or whichever type you have
statement.setInt(temp[3]); // int, or whichever type you have
statement.setInt(temp[4]); // int, or whichever type you have
// ^ for the above, if all fields are the same - you can do this in a loop


statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL); // execute the insert
```